# how to remove the alert message when opening Visual Studio Code with URI scheme

Tags: url, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if anyone knows a way to remove the alert message when opening Visual Studio Code with a scheme URI from Chrome like this: `vscode://file/{full path to file}`

I discovered this technique here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls
But when I don't know how to turn off this message.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

[image: External program warning]

Comment: That is kind of a security message and most likely will not be able to be removed

Comment: There is no way even in the settings ?

Comment: Removing security alert messages makes you vulnerable for attacks